# Where to find some powershell syntax

Tags: powershell

I was just reading some powershell script and I found that in some of them there is written things like: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand` OR `[System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)` OR `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom($_.FullName)` I mean where can I find the meaning of them? Is there any page on microsoft where there is a list of each of them and their proper meaning? Thanks

Comment: Typically text between `[]` is a combination of .NET name spaces and classes. It is easiest to search on those first. Those resulting pages will have class members listed. `::` is a static reference syntax. It is used to access static methods and properties. Methods have `()` or `(data)` at the end of their names when called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What did you search for?

All the docs are available online and doing what you are seeing is a very common thing. So, anytime you see this use case...

```
[System.
```

... this is calling the Windows .Net libraries for a target need. This is all covered on the MSDN and .Net docs site.

['powershell using .net classes'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20using%20.net%20classes&form=ANNTH1&refig=75341c2be473469aa298bd268e7a1629&sp=1&pq=powershell%20using%20.net%20&sc=6-22&qs=AS&sk=PRES1&cvid=75341c2be473469aa298bd268e7a1629)

Example Return

[PowerShell: How to Create and Use Classes](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27080.powershell-how-to-create-and-use-classes.aspx)

> PowerShell has the capability to create .Net Framework classes using
>   the Add-Type Jump cmdlet.  To create classes, the C# language can be
>   used to define the classes. C# is part of Visual Studio, but having
>   Visual Studio is not necessary to create classes for use in
>   PowerShell. The C# class definitions can be part of the PowerShell
>   script file. No DLL files to worry about installing.

```
$PeopleDefinition=@"
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace People
{
    public enum Gender

    {
        Unknown,
        Male,
        Female
    }

    public class Person  {}
    public class Persons {}
    public class People  {}
    public static class Factory {}
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $PeopleDefinition
Remove-Variable PeopleDefinition
$People = [People.Factory]::BuildPeople()
$Person = $People["Person"]
```

['powershell using .net namespace'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20using%20.net%20namespace%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20using%20.net%20namespac%27&sc=0-32&sk=&cvid=A5B5526513354BEC8C0CE8B561D7461B)

Example return:

[Discover the Dot NET Namespace and WMI Class-Powershell](http://Applies%20to%20Windows%20Server%202003,%20Windows%20Server%202003%20R2,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2,%20Windows%20Server%202012,%20Windows%20Server%202012%20R2%20https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25333.discover-the-dot-net-namespace-and-wmi-class-powershell.aspx)

> .NET Namespace-Powershell
>
> All Scripts in this Blog written using .NET Namespace so we don't have
>   the Module Dependency.
>
> Now a days there are so many Modules are available in Powershell. For
>   our daily operation those are very helpful.If we using built-in Module
>   there are few challenges like If we are used "ActiveDirectory" Module;
>   that module is available in Domain Controler or you need to install
>   that manually. In this case if we want manage our AD; we need
>   "ActiveDirectory" Module. That is the reason I am putting this topic
>   in this blog. If you are used .NET namespace you don't need the
>   Module.
>
> If we are used .NET name space instead of Powershell Module which is
>   available in all Windows 2008 System. Also we don't have any Module
>   available in Windows 2008 for manageing the Microsoft PKI.
>
> Given few important Namespaces those can make our life easier & we can
>   write our own code without the Powershell Module.
>
> 1. We can manage our Active Directory

```
NameSpace
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory]
```

Docs/info/examples/explanations for the items you specifically ask for could also be searched for just by using that exact string.

[$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%24ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%24executioncontext.invokecommand.getcommand&sc=0-42&sk=&cvid=9AAE2C2977D34C02BC8D636B70AB1E40)

[PowerShell Tip: To write a Proxy Function](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25075.powershell-tip-to-write-a-proxy-function.aspx)

```
[System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet]
```

> [Defines the types of commands that MSH can execute](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%5BSystem.Management.Automation.CommandTypes%5D%3A%3ACmdlet&form=ANSPH1&refig=70755b3c6a9749c28cf1e6509c7c1e73&sp=-1&pq=%5Bsystem.management.automation.commandtypes%5D%3A%3Acmdlet&sc=0-51&qs=n&sk=&cvid=70755b3c6a9749c28cf1e6509c7c1e73)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom]
```

> [Loads an assembly into the reflection-only context, given its path.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%5BSystem.Reflection.Assembly%5D%3A%3AReflectionOnlyLoadFrom&form=ANNTH1&refig=84642239dbde4276afc723c8b2b640b0&sp=-1&pq=%5Bsystem.reflection.assembly%5D%3A%3Areflectiononlyloadfrom&sc=0-52&qs=n&sk=&cvid=84642239dbde4276afc723c8b2b640b0)

***Update***

I meant to add these from Microsoft as well.

> ***[.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api)*** Welcome to the .NET API browser – your one-stop shop for all .NET-based APIs from Microsoft. Start searching
>   for any managed APIs by typing in the box below. You can learn more
>   about the API browser in our blog post. If you have any feedback,
>   create a new issue in the MicrosoftDocs/feedback repository on GitHub.

[Platform Invoke (P/Invoke)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke)

[How to: Call Native DLLs from Managed Code Using PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2019)

As well as this tool to lookup stuff, like what the .Net one above allows.

> [What is PInvoke.net?](https://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx)
>
> PInvoke.net is primarily a wiki, allowing developers to find, edit and
>   add PInvoke* signatures, user-defined types, and any other information
>   related to calling Win32 and other unmanaged APIs from managed code
>   (written in languages such as C# or VB.NET).

Here is an older PowerShell tool to browse classes, namespaces, but it is slow, becasue it takes a long while to populate when you select lists.

> [PowerShell Object Browser](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Object-Browser-847d62c1)
>
> This is a PowerShell application that displays objects in an explorer
>   type application written in PowerShell. The  PowerShell Object Browser
>   displays the properties and child objects / collections for any
>   PowerShell / .Net framework object.For an explantation on how to use
>   this a
>
> Download: [PSObjectBrowser.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Object-Browser-847d62c1/file/131075/1/PSObjectBrowser.ps1)